# Vague error when trying to bundle hybrid app for Tizen TV

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app, tizen-studio, tizen-sdk

My end goal is to create a hybrid app for Tizen TV so that I can run a scan on the local network for DLNA servers (With the Native part) and playback the content from said DLNA server(s) on the Web/UI part. (If this isn't going to be possible please let me know).

My current issue is I cannot seem to get the command to bundle a Hybrid app to work. Here is the command I have been using on Windows:

`$[TIZEN_STUDIO_DIR]/tools/ide/bin$ ./tizen package -t wgt -s [CERTIFICATE_PROFILE_NAME] -r [TPK_FILE_PATH] -- [WGT_FILE_PATH]`

(Command from https://docs.tizen.org/application/dotnet/get-started/hybrid-application/)

Output is:

```
PS C:\Users\User\Documents\tizen> tizen package -t wgt -s security-profile-name -r C:\Users\User\Documents\tizen\native\CrossTemplate1\CrossTemplate1\CrossTemplate1.Tizen.TV\bin\Debug\tizen60\org.tizen.example.CrossTemplate1.Tizen.TV-1.0.0.tpk

Error: C:\Users\User\Documents\tizen\native\CrossTemplate1\CrossTemplate1\CrossTemplate1.Tizen.TV\bin\Debug\tizen60\org.tizen.example.CrossTemplate1.Tizen.TV-1.0.0.tpk  must be web widget contents Directory
Web Widget App project's reference path must be web widget
error occured on packaging.
```

This is confusing because the article linked above specifically says that the -r argument should be a path to the .TPK file (followed by a - and path to WGT - but i'm on windows and this doesnt work). This error seems to indicate it should be the path to the WGT file? It doesn't work either way. Would really appreciate any help!

Here is the config.xml from the pre-existing WGT/Web app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns:tizen="http://tizen.org/ns/widgets" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" id="http://yourdomain/tizen" version="1.0.0" viewmodes="maximized">
    <access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
    <tizen:application id="Yi1xvJEX2n.ozone" package="Yi1xvJEX2n" required_version="2.3"/>
    <content src=""/>
    <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/screen.size.normal.1080.1920"/>
    <icon src="icon.png"/>
    <name>Ozone</name>
    <tizen:metadata key="http://samsung.com/tv/metadata/prelaunch.support" value="true"/>
    <tizen:profile name="tv"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/application.launch"/>
    <tizen:setting screen-orientation="landscape" context-menu="enable" background-support="disable" encryption="disable" install-location="auto" hwkey-event="enable"/>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command line seems to be incorrect, can't see the last part after the path to the .tpk, you should then have -- and the path to the wgt. Also worth noting is that docs says: "Hybrid application is not supported in the TV profile officially."

Comment: And FYI: I'm trying to solve a similar problem so happy to hear any progress you make

Comment: This was the correct answer, not sure why but I was sure that was working before. I've since made good progress with the Hybrid app, what are you struggling with?